# How to get checkbox checked value from Treeview in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, treeview

I want to get checkbox checked value from Treeview.

I bind the data from oracle database on Treeview.

Code:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        fill_Tree2();
    }

    void fill_Tree2()
    {

        DataSet PrSet = PDataset("Select * from Activity_Parent");

        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();

        foreach (DataRow dr in PrSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {

            TreeNode tnParent = new TreeNode();

            tnParent.CollapseAll();

            tnParent.Text = dr[1].ToString();

            tnParent.Value = dr[0].ToString();

            tnParent.ToolTip = "Click to get Child";

            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tnParent);

            FillChild(tnParent, tnParent.Value);

        }
    }

    public void FillChild(TreeNode parent, string ParentId)
    {

        DataSet ds = PDataset("Select * from Activity_child where Activity_ID =" + ParentId);

        parent.ChildNodes.Clear();

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {

            TreeNode child = new TreeNode();

            child.Text = dr["ActivityName"].ToString().Trim();

            child.Value = dr["ActivityChild_ID"].ToString().Trim();

            parent.ChildNodes.Add(child);
        }

    }

    protected DataSet PDataset(string Select_Statement)
    {

        OleDbConnection DbConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.SNIDB;Data Source=SNIDB;User ID=AZRAAR;Password=AZRAAR");

        OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(Select_Statement, DbConnection);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ad.Fill(ds);

        ViewState["ds"] = ds;

        return ds;

    }
```

In the below Button click event,I tried but it is not working

```
    protected void btnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds1= (DataSet)ViewState["ds"];
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds1.Tables[0].Rows)
        { 
          TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
          if (tn.Checked == true)
          {
              Response.Write(tn.Text);

          }
          tn.Text = dr["ActivityName"].ToString(); 
          TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tn); 
        } 
     }
}
```

In the below image if I select Checkbox HR Activity1, Developer Activity3 etc.,

I want to get that value

[image: Treeview]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain your schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to get a collection of all selected TreeNodes would be:

```
private List<TreeNode> AllCheckedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

private void GetAllCheckedNodes()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TreeView1.CheckedNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        AllCheckedNodes.Add(TreeView1.CheckedNodes[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your btnGet_Click method is not correct – you create new TreeView object in that method and that is not the object that exists on your page.

What you need to do is to create event handler for SelectedNodeChanged event.

Here is one line you should add to the fill_Tree2() method

```
private void FillTree()
{
    Treeview1.SelectedNodeChanged += Treeview1_SelectedNodeChanged;

}

protected void Treeview1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string value = Treeview1.SelectedNode.Value;
}
```

Also another mistake is having Page_Load method written like this. This will load your treview every time the page is reloaded (even on post back). What you want is something like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       fill_Tree2();
    }
}
```