# Creating a treeview with checkboxes from sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, treeview

I am planning to filter my gridview with the help of a treeview which shows the State and its respective cities.So can anyone link me up with a good tutorial on the same.I have tried my best to find one but nothing is working.It will be helpful if i also find a way to retrieve that checkboxes that i have checked.Lokking for something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just get checked nodes like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18569421/2606291):

```
private List<TreeNode> AllCheckedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

private void GetAllCheckedNodes()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TreeView1.CheckedNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        AllCheckedNodes.Add(TreeView1.CheckedNodes[i]);
    }
}
```

then write a query to be displayed in gridview filtered upon this result.